# How to make a complete factory reset, without anyone being able to retrieve my data?

Tags: factory-reset, data-recovery, delete, privacy

I will have a few Android phones that I will have to let go.

I would like to make a proper clean wipe of the data, without no one being able to retrieve them, and do a factory reset.

I have read about the [Schneier Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_erasure), encrypting the device before doing a factory reset, doing both, etc.

Since I am not an Android/adb guru, I would like to know if some of you would have some idea on how to achieve this with certainty.

I know "certainty" is a big word when it comes to proper data erasure on flash memory but still.

I have found some answers here and somewhere else, saying that encrypting and doing a factory reset on your Android device is enough, but I could not find a reliable source.

Just a few information that could be useful:

- I'm running Linux as my OS and, therefore, I'm not looking for a Windows-based solution
- My devices are non-rooted and (almost) identical (Samsung A510F + 1 A510FD)

Comment: this device is encrypted by default. in order to avoid FRP lock, enable OEM unlocking in developer settings (if it exist), then just do a normal factory reset

Comment: @alecxs I could just remove my Google account before doing the factory reset in order to avoid the FRP lock, or am I missing something?

Comment: yes, removing google account is fine too

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### HOW DELETED DATA IS RECOVERED?

Data (un)deletion strongly depends on how a storage media (`HDD`, `SSD`, `eMMC` etc.), filesystem (`NTFS`, `FAT32`, `ext4` etc.) and OS save and delete files.

- File carving / signature search / content-aware recovery identifies standard signatures values in the headers of deleted files (as `file` command and antivirus programs do to identify known viruses hiding in files) e.g. JPEG files start with `0xffd8` and end with `0xffd9`. The data in between blocks is assumed to be the file (considering the file is contiguous; no fragmentation). Other checks may also be performed on header like a checksum, the file’s length, or date/time etc. But not all file types have a standard header/footer signature, so determining where the file starts/ends is difficult. Metadata (including filenames) isn't recovered with this method.

  This approach works for deleted files, filesystems or partitions. `Photorec`, `scalpel`, `foremost` and popular Android app `DiskDigger` (in dig deeper mode) work on this approach.
- Recovering as much as possible information about deleted data blocks from within filesystem e.g. from `directory entries`, `journal`, `inodes` etc. Filesystem is basically the catalog which holds *file name vs. file location* information and journal is a kind of backup information. So recovery of filenames (and other metadata) is more probable with `journaling` filesystems.

  This approach works only if filesystem and partition are intact, or are recoverable using first method. `DiskDigger` (in dig deep mode) and `extundelete` work on this approach.

---

### WHAT MAKES RECOVERY OF DELETED DATA DIFFICULT / IMPOSSIBLE?

- A file/directory is simply deleted e.g. from some File Explorer app or with `rm` from commadline.
- A file is renamed to some random string, then deleted.
- Filesystem on the device is not [journaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journaling_file_system), so no information can be collected from `journal`. `Ext4`, the commonly used filesystem on Android, is `journaling`.
- Filesystem on the device is a [Flash Filesystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_file_system) e.g. `F2FS`.

  In this case you are left with minimum tools (e.g. no [debugfs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/debugfs.8.html) to list deleted `inodes` and to lookup corresponding data blocks from `journal`) and also data is always written to new blocks as a wear-leveling strategy. [`Garbage Collection`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F2FS#Cleaning_process) makes recovery less probable from filesystem because Logical Block Addresses ([LBAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_block_addressing)) of data blocks get changed. So only `carving method` is applicable, and [it works](https://www.digitalforensics.com/blog/forensic-analysis-of-flash-friendly-file-system-f2fs).
- Filesystem or partition is deleted, making it harder to search `directory structures` and `journal` from within filesystem. Android's stock recovery deletes filesystem during a Factory Reset. See [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214029/218526).
- Whole disk is erased including [Partition Table](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/info-android-device-partitions-basic-t3586565), boundaries of partitions and filesystems are vanished. This isn't possible on Android devices because there are partitions required to boot the device.
- File was [fragmented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragmentation_(computing)) (not saved contiguously as a single piece), particularly if no information can be recovered from filesystem.

  Fragmentation is higher on Windows as compared to Linux/Android; `Ext4` is self de-fragmenting because of *Delayed Allocation* and *reserved-blocks-percentage* etc. But usually large files on an older filesystem are always fragmented.
- You overwrite file/filesystem/partition with other file/filesystem/partition, or zeros, or random data (`shredding`).

  If you have root access, throw a stream of `/dev/urandom` on block device to overwrite all data including filesystem. Now forget about its recovery, though it doesn't nullify the possibility of data recovery directly from flash storage (raw NAND), by chipping it off the board (who will do this except in forensic lab!). Official tool from SD organization: [SD Memory Card Formatter](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter/) also overwrites with `zeros` in full format mode. Please note that repeated overwriting wastes precious E/P cycles of flash memory.
- Filesystem is `TRIMmed` or `SECURE TRIMmed`, or `ERASEd` or `SECURE ERASEd`.

  These are [special commands](https://source.android.com/security/overview/implement#unlockable-bootloaders) for different types of flash storage devices. `TRIM` is issued by the filesystem to the firmware of flash device, requesting the actual physical erasure of data blocks (`LBAs`) which have been deleted from the filesystem. Filesystems mounted with `discard` option always send `FITRIM ioctl` whenever a file is deleted. Android does a scheduled TRIM, or you can do manually with `fstrim` command. See [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214087/218526).
- Partition is `BLKDISCARDed` or `BLKSECDISCARDed`.

  [blkdiscard](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/blkdiscard.8.html) issues TRIM command for whole block device i.e. partition or disk (roughly equivalent to issuing TRIM on a newly created filesystem).
  `TRIM` saves filesystem's `superblocks`/`inode` table and drive's partition table, `BLKDISCARD` saves nothing on block device.

  Android's stock recovery tries to do at least one of the both during a Factory Reset. See [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214029/218526).
  Something similar happens with [bootloader unlock](https://source.android.com/security/overview/implement#unlockable-bootloaders) and [`fastboot erase`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r45/fastboot/README.md), though it depends on implementation inside bootloader but that's what Google expects from OEM/SoC vendors.
- Deleted file is encrypted or file doesn't have an [identifiable unique signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) (at start or end), so no carving is possible.

  Like an encrypted archive or file that mostly file explorers can create. Or a file with some uncommon format, not known to recovery programs.
- Filesystem or block device is encrypted so the data becomes unrecognizable (like [`FBE`/`FDE`](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/) on Android). Mostly new devices come with `forceencrypt` or `fileencryption` flags set in `fstab`, so `vold` encrypts them on first usage. If not decryptable (e.g. formatted), data is impossible to be recovered on such devices.
- Flash storage device is `self-encrypting`, common for `SSDs` but not for `eMMCs`.
- Flash storage device is erased with `SECURITY_ERASE` or `ENHANCED_SECURITY_ERASE` ATA commands, common for `SSDs` but not for `eMMCs`.
- Storage device isn't accessible e.g. on embedded system if bootloader is erased, device is bricked and no more bootable. There is no protocol to communicate with eMMC, even if the data is there, except through something very lower level like `JTAG` or a chip-off.

  Also see: [Bootloader/BIOS, flashing ROM and correlated risks. Why Android devices are more brickable than PCs?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205552/218526)
- Storage media is physically damaged; mechanically or electrically.

Large size storage solutions like `NAS` or the more complicated `SAN` that makes use of `LUNs` with advanced protocols likes `iSCSI`, and data integrity solutions like `RAID` also complicate the data recovery process. However single disks like on home PCs or the flash memory like on Android phones are rather simple cases.

---

So while a Factory Reset with stock recovery suffices in most cases, you can combine any of the above described steps, whichever applicable to your device, to make sure your data is not retrievable.

**RELATED:**

- [Can user data be recovered after formatting and flashing stock ROM?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214497/218526)
- [How to recover a deleted file from /data partition?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/208114/218526)
- [How to get data off a completely dead Android phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/215445/218526)