# Recovering data from formatted sdcard in Android

Tags: backup, external-sd, data-recovery, formatting

I have a rooted android phone running android 10. My 128gb sdcard with filesystem exFAT, had data of about 100GB. When I inserted it in my phone. My phone did not show the sdcard contents and asked me to format it. So I formatted it and sdcard worked normally.
Then I tried to recover data by creating raw image of sdcard using

```
dd if=/dev/block/sdd  of=/mnt/meda_rw/BACKUP/sd.img
```

But this created `sd.img` of size 8MB which is equal to the size of current contents in sdcard(which android created automatically after formatting).

After that I looked up the mounted sdcard entry using `df -h` command, shown as :

```
/dev/block/vold/public:179,1    119G  8.6M  119G   1% /mnt/media_rw/AC8C-9FF9
```

Ran :

```
dd if='/dev/block/vold/public:179,1'  of=/mnt/meda_rw/BACKUP/sdd.img
```

This time, it created a raw file `sdd.img` of size 119GB.

I tried to recover data from the generated 119 GB `sdd.img` using testdisk, photorec, r-studio, disk drill etc. But none of them detected any file and showed 'Found 0 files & 0 directories'.

Note. My sdcard is stuck now in the slot & I cannot remove it as doing so might damage the pins.

Why `dd` cmd is creating `sd.img` of size 8MB only from `/dev/block/sdd` ?

Has the sdcard been completely wiped by android (during formatting process) due to which it is not possible to recover data now?

How can I recover data from sdcard now?

Comment: It is not possible to remove sdcard now.  Is there any low level data recovery method within android ?   I have chrooted linux in android phone. May be any linux utility could help ?

Answer (score 1):

For Linux, as specified in the comment, [Foremost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foremost_(software)) can be used. For the `dd` image [Sleuthkit](https://www.sleuthkit.org/sleuthkit/download.php) with [Autopsy](https://www.autopsy.com/download/) can help. Another option is to use [SIFT Workstation](https://www.sans.org/tools/sift-workstation/), in a virtual machine, which contains tools that can also be helpful.

Note that the data can be recovered only if the SD card was not trimmed:
[If I reset my phone, will it also TRIM the fragmented eMMC?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/213432/if-i-reset-my-phone-will-it-also-trim-the-fragmented-emmc)