# Does Android 8 has journaling enabled in its ext4 files sytem?

Tags: data-recovery, file-system, internal-sd, operating-system, ext4

Android 8 uses stackable file sytem called `sdcardfs`, which emulates FAT32 on `ext4` on the data partition. Does `sdcardfs` recognize the `ext4` file system and journaling?
In other words, files written using `sdcardfs` has journal history information created?

On Android 8 it's not clear how the `journaling` works e.g. can it be used to recover data? Is the new data written to empty fresh areas or first the deleted areas are used?

Answer (score 1):

> Does Android 8 has journaling enabled in its `ext4` files system?

It depends on a few factors. OEMs can possibly disable journaling e.g. on `system` partition as it's always supposed to be used R/O. These days `ext4` and `f2fs` are commonly used filesystems on Android, so first make sure you have `ext4` on `userdata` partition. `f2fs` is by-origin a `log-structured` filesystem which is a `circular buffer`, that's what a journal is but the functionality differs.

Filesystems are part of Linux kernel, not Android (AOSP) itself. `ext4` by default is created with journal, though it depends on [`mke2fs.conf`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/e2fsprogs/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r47/misc/mke2fs.conf.in#14), and can be disabled with [`mke2fs`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mke2fs.8.html) or [`tune2fs`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/tune2fs.8.html) option `-O ^has_journal`.  Journaling support can be checked from filesystem features by executing `tune2fs -l /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/userdata | grep has_journal` (or use `dm-0` block device if `userdata` has FDE) but it requires root. As alternate if `mount | grep 'on /data'` shows [`data={journal|ordered|writeback}`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ext4.5.html) option then journal is enabled for sure.

> Does `sdcardfs` recognize the `ext4` file system and journaling?

`sdcardfs` itself doesn't have a journal, but since emulated filesystem is stacked over `/data/media` (which is `ext4`), the files created through `sdcardfs` are recorded in underlying filesystem's journal.

> On Android 8 it's not clear how the `journaling` works e.g. can it be used to recover data?

Yes definitely, if you have root already and the data isn't overwritten. We have tools like `extundelete` which are very effective. But do consider factors like `TRIM` and others described below and in given links.

> Is the new data written to empty fresh areas or first the deleted areas are used?

Well that's a different question, again it has nothing to do with Android. The question is ***how often a filesystem overwrites deleted data blocks*** and it's not simple to answer. Create a new `ext4` filesystem, create a file *foo* inside it and delete it. Create new file *bar* and it will take the inode block and data blocks freed by *foo*. Delete *bar* and create file *baz*, it will occupy the same space. However in actual things are complicated. Will the data blocks of deleted file be immediately overwritten or not depends on whats the size of new file is, how much fragmented your filesystem is, how much free LBAs you have before the logical location of deleted file etc.

**PS:**
Things are different on `f2fs`, it's the **F**lash **F**riendly **F**ile**S**ystem, so as a wear-leveling strategy it preferably writes data to new empty blocks (free segments), so that `FTL` doesn't have to Erase cells, trying to reduce the E/P counts on flash memory. Later it does background garbage collection (GC) synchronized with FTL to release LBAs corresponding to deleted data. But the tools like [`debugfs`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/debugfs.8.html) aren't readily available for `f2fs` to explore deleted inodes and to lookup corresponding data blocks from `journal`. So from data recovery's view, `f2fs` isn't very *friendly* (AFAIK and experienced).

**RELATED:** [What Makes Recovery of Deleted Data Difficult / Impossible?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214496/218526)

Comment: Where would I find the journal file itself? I'm actually looking for the journal file of the 2nd partition (ext4 partition) of a micro SD card that is inserted in the device.

Comment: @Sruly journal is stored in an invisible file usually located at inode 8. See https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Journal_.28jbd2.29 or any other EXT4 resource. It's not specifically about Android.