# recover/restore deleted photos Android

Tags: photos, delete

ten days ago I deleted some photos (also from the trash). Is there even the slightest chance that they can be recovered, even forensically?

Or Trim/garbage collection have already done their job?
I'm not a great expert but as soon as you delete something trim is already working in the background, you should turn off your phone immediately to have even the slightest chance with chip-off, ten days is a long time.

(regardless of whether my phone is Oreo with FDE by default, let's just talk about trim)

thanks

Comment: there is a slight chance if really FDE encrypted. I remember that there was an issue with discard not executing immediately trim on /data. create raw partition image of userdata+metadata partition for backup with low level tool (edl or brom mode) then root phone and try [extundelete](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/215448).