# Wipe personal data from android mobile without rooting

Tags: rooting

I apologize If placing a already answered questions. But I am novice and have tried finding answers to no avail.

I got a Moto G3 (2015) from a friend and I want to erase all his personal data to the extent of unrecoverable to ensure protection of his privacy.

I can root it using TWRP, Supersu, Magisk as I found on many websites/ forums. But I have following question/ agitation in my mind.

1. Rooting will left me not able to run some app like bank apps as they do not run on rooted mobile.
2. Will I be able to factory reset my mobile after rooting mobile using custom recovery image i.e.  TWRP, Supersu, Magisk .
3. Will these files be safe.

So to get rid of all these problems I do not want to root my device at all.
4. can I wipe/ erase all personal data securely with multi pass using a an open source app/ adb from internal memory.
5. does Android store log files and temp files as in Linux in /var/log/. How can I erase them without rooting.
6. If I am wrong and I can root my device without any problem. Please advice me.

The answer to question suggested by Irfan is not specific to my question. Through it is a good post for common knowledge but did not tell How to to a novice.

Thank You.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a complete factory reset, without anyone being able to retrieve my data?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/213275/how-to-make-a-complete-factory-reset-without-anyone-being-able-to-retrieve-my-d)

Comment: you can do factory reset from phone settings. but take care of FRP lock, remove all google play accounts or enable OEM unlocking in developer settings before

Comment: Thank You Irfan It is a whole chapter. I had unlocked boot-loader officially(just for information). I put big movie files and encrypted the mobile and then ran factory reset. Was it enough. I am not talking of ordinary recovery. I want it completely unrecoverable.

Comment: a simple factory reset from android settings is enough. reason: the encryption keys wiped on factory reset. without the keys everything is just unrecoverable garbage, no need to overwrite userdata multi pass. even with recovered encryption keys it is not possible to decrypt without proper lockscreen password. not even bruteforce is possible for 6+ digit pin, because android has bruteforce protections, timeouts, auto-wipe etc (and offline-bruteforcing is not possible too, encryption is hardware-bound)

Comment: for some old qualcomm devices there was once a crack into keymaster which could leak the hardware keys and made offline bruteforce possible. but that is long fixed
https://www.theregister.com/2016/07/01/turns_out_breaking_android_fulldisk_encryption_is_easy_with_the_right_code
https://www.synacktiv.com/en/publications/kinibi-tee-trusted-application-exploitation.html