# How to format the internal memory of a Huawei Mate 20 Lite?

Tags: security, huawei, formatting, reformat

I have a Huawei Mate 20 lite I need to format its internal memory.

I don't mean to *reset* it to factory defaults.

I mean I have to format it, that is, I have to overwrite the internal memory with 0s (or with random data and then with 0s).

How to do that?

I have a Linux desktop.

Comment: Could you explain what you want to achieve? Modern Android devices by default encrypt user data. In such a case you don't have to erase all data only the used encryption key. Afterward the data is better erased that any overwrite which is not that simple with flash memory because of overprovisioning, reserve sectors, ... Overwriting is more useful for simple magnetic media like HDDs.

Comment: @Robert i am trying to trash my old mobile phone without Mallory recovering my data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a complete factory reset, without anyone being able to retrieve my data?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/213275/how-to-make-a-complete-factory-reset-without-anyone-being-able-to-retrieve-my-d)