# Are my personal files safe after factory reset?

Tags: security, factory-reset, privacy

I am planning to sell my phone Redmi Note 7 running Android 9 which is already unlocked bootloader but no root access, is my data can still be recovered through Android software recovery? I don't want the new owner to recovered my personal data. and I read somewhere that Android factory reset does not actually delete your file and still can be recovered. Is this safe to just only factory reset?

Comment: Most likely what you have read is at least 3-5 years old and refers to older Android versions before all devices are mandatory encrypted by default.

Comment: Android 9 has encryption by default. Factory reset clears encryption keys from TEE so recovered data cannot be decrypted.

Comment: Possibly related: [How to make a complete factory reset, without anyone being able to retrieve my data?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/213275/44325)