# Reset factory and recovery in android

Tags: security, recovery-mode, factory-reset, xiaomi

I want to reset my phone. After resetting, can photos be recovered with recovery software? If not, what can I do to prevent deleted photos from being recovered?
My phone: redmi note 9pro

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a complete factory reset, without anyone being able to retrieve my data?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/213275/how-to-make-a-complete-factory-reset-without-anyone-being-able-to-retrieve-my-d)

Comment: TL;DR *"Factory Reset [...] suffices in most cases"*