# Does d2d transfer all system data?

Tags: data-recovery, data-transfer

I want to recover my deleted notes (which is located in data folder that need root to access) and i'm going to try d2d transfer today. But i want to know does phone transfer systems transfer all data include system folders? Because i want to recover deleted files which are probably being there in compressed form(i hope so).After i transfer to the rooted phone(mine is not), i'm going to use data recover apps to save and see them.Once i tried a program in my pc and i couldnt believe my eyes after all reset over years this program showed a lot of pictures and videos from 10 years ago. And if i use d2d, will data be on 2 phone or will they deleted in my phone after i transfer? Thank you i want to finish that recover notes i'm trying for months and if i cannot succeed in this, I will give up and break the phone.

Comment: 10 year old phones are not comparable of recent phones as recent phones have built-in file-based encryption which makes common file-recovery tools useless as deleted files are encrypted by a key that is next to impossible to recover. https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214496/2241