# Do photos survive a factory reset (Android)?

Tags: data-recovery, factory-reset, photos

I sold my old Oreo but I'm paranoid.
I had about twenty old photos (nothing special) and I deleted them, even from the trash. Then factory reset.

I recorded some blank videos and then a factory reset. Another x2 factory reset.

(I didn't have screen lock)

I know, Oreo is FBE but I still don't know if those encrypted files remain there or are deleted via garbage collection with the use of the phone.

My real question is this: in 6 months will those stupid encrypted files still be on the phone or will they have already been removed? Will they be there forever inaccessible?

Comment: Did you have many Android environments/workspace in that phone? An environment/workspace is similar to the Microsoft Windows feature where multiple users can login to a single computer.

Comment: Related: [How to recover a deleted file from /data partition on a rooted phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/208106/44325) & [How to make a complete factory reset, without anyone being able to retrieve my data?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/213275/44325)

Comment: Related: [Should I trust that the Android factory reset actually erases my data?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/248367/should-i-trust-that-the-android-factory-reset-actually-erases-my-data)

Answer (score 4):

> I sold my old Oreo but I'm paranoid. I had about twenty old photos
> (nothing special) and I deleted them, even from the trash. Then
> factory reset.

That should be enough. As explained on security.SE:

> All android 7+ devices are enrolled with File Based Encryption (FBE)
> that encrypts /data partition from first boot. FBE keys are bound to
> TEE [Trusted Execution Environment] and user screen lock authentication.
> **On factory reset, TEE clears stored keys and OS wipes the data.**
> At this point, even if your screen
> lock password is known, it's not possible to decrypt recovered data.

*[Should I trust that the Android factory reset actually erases my data?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/248367/should-i-trust-that-the-android-factory-reset-actually-erases-my-data)*

So yes, a factory reset is enough to delete everything - because the data is encrypted, and the reset throws away the key.

> I know, Oreo is FBE but I still don't know if those encrypted files
> remain there or are deleted via garbage collection with the use of the
> phone.

The encrypted files may remain, but it does not matter, as the key is gone.

> My real question is this: in 6 months will those stupid encrypted
> files still be on the phone or will they have already been removed?
> Will they be there forever inaccessible?

Maybe they will, but again, it does not matter.

Barring any bugs in the implementation, the data is gone forever.

---

One caveat would be: This does not necessarily apply to data on the **external SD card**. So if you have one, make sure to wipe it separately (or just take it out :-) ).

Comment: only for curiosity: why these encrypted useless inacessible "files" may remain? shouldn't they be overwritten with the use? shouldn't they be part of garbage collection?

Comment: @rizzi66: Because "overwrite" slowly wears out the flash, it's best to do it only when needed.  Since the data is impossible to decrypt, there's no need to "overwrite" it.